# How do you take away a certain amount items from a player and then give back an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map, and I want to have a command block or a command block set in the middle of the map that detects when a player picks up 5 diamonds and then replaces those diamonds with a bow and arrow. I've found the command

```
/execute if data entity @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:5b}]}
```

But the only way I've gotten that to work with anything is to do a `/give @p command`, but because I want this command to be working with multiple people on the map it won't work, How can I take this output and use it to both clear the diamonds and give 2 items?

Comment: [Related, but not quite a duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/237014/1351)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. More magic from `/execute` can split each player's handling to themselves. Using scoreboard tags, we can then target the players individually.

```
execute
  as @a                                                             # Tell all players to do the following:
  if data entity @s {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:5b}]} # If I have 5 diamonds, continue, otherwise stop.
run tag @s add diamondBow                                           # give myself a recognizable tag.
```

Then, just run the following in order:

```
clear @a[tag=diamondBow] minecraft:diamond 5 # Clear the diamonds
give @a[tag=diamondBow] minecraft:bow        # Give the bow
give @a[tag=diamondBow] minecraft:arrow      # Give the arrow
tag @a[tag=diamondBow] remove diamondBow     # Get rid of the tag
```

Note that in order to work, all 5 diamonds must be stacked in one slot, not spread out through the inventory. If you want to detect 5 diamonds spread out anywhere in the inventory, replace the `/execute` command with the following two:

```
/execute as @a store result score @s itemsCleared run clear @s minecraft:diamond 0
/tag @a[scores={itemsCleared=5}] add diamondBow
```

Comment: You shouldn't do NBT inventory testing if you're looking to get an accurate count for a particular item, it's incredibly unreliable.  Instead you should execute a clear command (clearing 0 items) and save the result to a scoreboard.

Comment: @MBraedley You are technically correct, I just used this method because it was the method the OP was using.