# How to /testfor 10 wheat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to `/testfor` 10 wheat anywhere in the players inventory.

I have tried this command:

`testfor @a {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Count:10b­,id:minecraft:wheat}]}`

But it gives me this same error all the time:

`The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`

How can I do this?

Comment: And another [related answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235841/1351)

Answer (score 7):

> `The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`

That error is for the target selector, which usually occurs when no target was found (and is unrelated to the remainder of the command). Ensure there are targets available first or that there are no typos in your selector.

Using direct NBT detection will not reliably allow you to count the number of items. If you look specifically for a `Count` of 10, you'll only find wheat in an exact stack of 10 in a single slot, rather than 10 wheat spread across the inventory in any number of slots.

To accomplish that, you'll need to use CommandStats, which sets a score related to the success of a command. The `AffectedItems` trigger will set a score based on the number of items found.

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to hold the value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add ItemCount dummy
```

The `AffectedItems` trigger to apply to the player. This may need to run on a clock if new players can join at any time. The players will set their own "ItemCount" score based on the success of a command relevant to `AffectedItems` (such as `/give`, `/clear`, and `/replaceitem`).

```
/stats entity @a set AffectedItems @a[c=1] ItemCount
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a target's score, that target must be tracked in the objective prior. This may also need to run on a clock.

```
/scoreboard players add @a ItemCount 0
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Cause all players to clear 0 wheat in their inventory. While this does not remove any wheat, the command will return an `AffectedItems` value equal to the number of items that *could* have been cleared.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ clear @a[c=1] minecraft:wheat -1 0
   ```
2. Players will then have their "ItemCount" score set equal to the number of wheat all across their inventory, regardless if they're not in the same stack. You can then target players based on their score, which also allows for a range of values (which is otherwise not possible with direct NBT detection).

   ```
   /say @a[score_ItemCount_min=10] has 10 wheat.
   ```

Comment: `QueryResult` also works, AFAIK.

Comment: @MBraedley It does not. QueryResult only returns a value for very specific commands, being `/gamerule <gamerule>`, `/list`, `/scoreboard players list`, `/scoreboard players list <player>`, `/scoreboard teams list`, `/scoreboard teams list <team>`, `/time query <daytime|gametime|day>`, `/worldborder get`, and `/xp <0|0L> <player>`.

Comment: Oh, you're running the stats on the players, not on the command block like I've done previously.  That makes sense, then.

Comment: @MBraedley Well, even setting on a block instead of player would still require the use of `AffectedItems`, since the type of executor does not change the function of the triggers. Using `/stats` on players for cases like this is to allow multiplayer support, as otherwise only the last target obtained by a command block would affect the resulting score (for example, if 19 out of 20 players has 10+ wheat, but the last player targeted does not, the resulting `AffectedItems` will be misrepresented and assumed that no players at all have 10+ wheat, which can be detrimental if relying on the value).

Comment: So take a look at how I did it in the linked answer.  I know it works fine in single player, but now you're making me wonder if it works for multiplayer.

Comment: Using `/stats block` in general won't support multiplayer due to using the success of the single command block rather than success per-player. The resulting CommandStats score is assigned to all players, not the players that were found by the `/clear` command, so even those players that were not found by `/clear` will be labeled as if they were (it'll also need to be `AffectedItems` and not `QueryResult`). Using `/stats block` would be more suited for storing data that isn't meant to be used to target players directly, such as the number of entities or number of blocks in an area.